# MSBuild does not compile resource files

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a solution with multiple projects (it's a Silverlight application). Many of projects in solution contains resources (resx) files. When I build solution with Visual Studio everything is compiled and embedded ok (for example en-US folder in XAP file), but when I build the same solution with MSBuild the resource files are not compiled/embedded into XAP files.
How do you tell MSBuild to process resource files like Visual Studio do?

Comment: IIRC, this is some known problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this article [Building Localized XAP Resource Files For Silverlight 4 by Guy Smith-Ferrier](http://www.guysmithferrier.com/post/2010/10/Building-Localized-XAP-Resource-Files-For-Silverlight-4.aspx) could point you in the right direction where in you need to add the following lines to the bottom of your .csproj file:-

```
<Import Project="$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\I18N\Silverlight\v4.0\Silverlight.Build.Tasks.targets" />
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="XapResourcePackager"> 
</Target>
```

Then you add the following line immediately below your .csproj's `</SupportedCultures>` line:-

```
<PackageCultures>en-US</PackageCultures>
```

(where `<PackageCultures>` contains a comma delimited list of cultures to create XAP resource files for).

You will of course need to download the [MSBuild tasks](http://www.guysmithferrier.com/Downloads/Silverlight.Build.Tasks.zip) with the source code to build a library of MSBuild tasks (Silverlight.Build.Tasks.dll) and an MSBuild targets file (Silverlight.Build.Tasks.targets) that you add to your Silverlight application's .csproj file.